# Vanilla Node js Server, Css not loaded

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a web server application for my Frontend.
The structure is for the fronted files is :

```
Backend
server.js
Fronted
  Index
    Javascript
     index.js
  style.css
index.html (it is outside of Frontend folder)
```

The code for server.js is:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 5000;


const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     fs.readFile('../Frontend/index.html', function (error, data) {
        response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "text/html");
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Error: File Not Found');
            } else {
              response.write(data);
            }
            response.end();
        })
})

server.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong ', error);
    } else {
        
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);
    }
});
```

When I try to access localhost:5000 the HTML code shows, but without CSS, js or images, but when I am looking in the console at the network all the files are there (index.js, style.css, the images);

Comment: Your code only sends one file for all requests - index.html. You need to `fs.readFile()` the css file when the browser request css. How do you know what file the browser is requesting? You need to read the `request` object.

Comment: @slebetman could you help me with some code examples, please?

Comment: Why are you trying to use vanilla node? It'd be easier and better with some framework.

Comment: @VladyslavYukhanov because of something called faculty/ college...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the results you want as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 5000;
const http = require('http');


const server = http.createServer( function (request, response) {
    let filePath = '.'+request.url; //assumes your static  files are  
                                    // placed in the root directory 
    if(request.url ==='/' ||request.url==='/index.html'){
        filePath = './index.html';
        fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, data) {
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');;
                if (error) {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write('Error: File Not Found');
                }
                response.end(data,'utf-8');
            })  
    } else if(request.url==='/index.css'){
        filePath = './index.css';
        fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, data) {
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');;
                if (error) {
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write('Error: File Not Found');
                }
                response.end(data,'utf-8');
            })  
    }  //maybe some additional else if for image and so on or you can improve 
       //this logic but anyway this code gives you the right direction
    
        
})

server.listen(port, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong ', error);
    } else {
        
        console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);
    }
});
```